# Jquery flot co-dependent line + pie chart

Tags: jquery, flot, pie-chart, linechart

I've created an ajax driven flot line chart that I would like to have represented along side a flot pie chart using the summed data from the line chart.

Data for the line chart might look something like this:

```
var datasets = {
    "usa": {
        label: "USA",
        data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
    },        
    "russia": {
        label: "Russia",
        data: [[1988, 218000], [1989, 203000], [1990, 171000], [1992, 42500], [1993, 37600], [1994, 36600], [1995, 21700], [1996, 19200], [1997, 21300], [1998, 13600], [1999, 14000], [2000, 19100], [2001, 21300], [2002, 23600], [2003, 25100], [2004, 26100], [2005, 31100], [2006, 34700]]
    },
    etc...
};
```

What would be the easiest way aggregate this data so that it would be fit for the pie chart plug-in?  If I feed this current result set to the pie chart, it will only consider the first value of each dataset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an approach that combined the results for each chart into one json response on the server side and then pulled them out on the client like thus:

```
var datasets = {
"usa-line": {
    label: "USA",
    data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
},  
"usa-pie": {
    label: "USA",
    data: [[1, TOTAL GOES HERE]]]
},        
"russia-line": {
    label: "Russia",
    data: [[1988, 218000], [1989, 203000], [1990, 171000], [1992, 42500], [1993, 37600], [1994, 36600], [1995, 21700], [1996, 19200], [1997, 21300], [1998, 13600], [1999, 14000], [2000, 19100], [2001, 21300], [2002, 23600], [2003, 25100], [2004, 26100], [2005, 31100], [2006, 34700]]
},
"russia-pie": {
    label: "Russia",
    data: [[1, TOTAL GOES HERE]]]
}
};
```

Then on the callback for the ajax event, I parsed them out into separate datasets for each graph:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "url goes here",
        data: "data goes here",
        success: function (datasets) {         
            linedata = [];
            pieData = [];

            $.each (datasets, function (objName) {
                if(objName.indexOf('-line') != -1)
                    linedata .push(datasets[objName]);
                        else
                    pieData.push(datasets[objName]);
            });                       

            $.plot(plotarea, linedata , options /* options defined elsewhere */);
            $.plot(piearea, pieData, pieOptions /* pieOptions defined elsewhere */);  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to graph the the value separately for each year, like this:

Make the year selectable by some appropriate component such as increment/decrement buttons. For the year selected, plot the respective value for each country.
For example, in year 1988, plot 483994 for USA and 218000 for Russia.